# Why doesn't [.\n]+ match the string 'a\nb'?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my js Regex test.

```
'AAa\nbBB'.match(/AA[.\n]+BB/);//failed match
```

I thought `[.\n]+` could match any characters. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The dot matches a literal dot inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Use `'AAa\nbBB'.match(/AA[\s\S]*BB/);` instead.

In most regex flavors, you could set the `/s` flag to allow the dot to match newlines (for a regex like `/AA.*BB/s`). But in JavaScript, that feature is not available, so you need to use `[\s\S]` to match any character.

Comment: `[^]` is a shorter equivalent to `[\s\S]`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes, but that only works in JavaScript. At least `[\s\S]` is portable.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It's not really portable. It doesn't work in grep for example. I don't see how portability is relevant here. `(.|\n)` is more readable anyhow, if you don't mind the capturing group.